# Separating the OS and applications from current drive to a new drive

Tags: macos, hard-drive, migration

I want to change the way my Mac system is setup.

I currently have one large hard drive that has all the OS, applications and user data stored on it.

I would like to purchase a separate hard drive (preferably SSD), and have ONLY the Mac OS and applications installed on this. I will then use the current disk to store all user and applications data, files, media, etc.

My question is, how can I SAFELY migrate the Mac OS and Applications to the new drive but leave all other data on the current drive?

Comment: Ouch you might be out of luck, save important documents, reinstall on SSD, install applications?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it:

1. Backup the harddrive on a a backup drive (this could be done with Time Machine)
2. Fresh reinstall of OSX on the SSD
3. Follow [this](http://www.macworld.com/article/1164891/keeping_mac_os_and_data_on_separate_drives.html) to setup the home on a different partition
4. Use the migration assistant <strike>to grab accounts</strike> and App from the backup drive.

Because I'm lazy and coping/backing up takes for ever I would not wipe the hard drive and just rename `/Users` or try to use it as is directly actually :P and skipping step 4.1 (where 4.2 would be moving Apps to the SSD).